# Convert number to reversed array of digits (Scanner + Print-Method)

Tags: java

I want to get an Array with the reversed number when I invoke the method (Given a random non-negative number, you have to return the digits of this number within an array in reverse order.)
I initalised a scanner, but whenever I execute, I only get the address in the heap I suppose (for example: [I@66a29884).
I know this problem also occurs when we have String, which why we have the toString-Method.
Is there a way I can print the array or the reversed numbers out in the console?

```
public class ConvertNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Long n = Long.parseLong(scanner.nextLine());
        digitize(n);
    }
    public static int[] digitize(long n) {
        int[] digitized =  new StringBuilder().append(n).reverse().chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray() ;
        System.out.println(digitized);
        return  digitized;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `Long` to `String` because `[I@66a29884)` is String. using java stream you can reverse string easily.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static String digitize(String n) {
        return Stream.of(n)
            .map(str->new StringBuilder(str).reverse())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = scanner.next();
        System.out.print(digitize(n));
    }
}
```